# Ansible db2 task executing script geting error

Tags: linux, ansible, db2, task

I have a task in Ansible to execute sql script from db2server

```yaml
- name: Execute db2 script
    ansible.builtin.shell: '/db2/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2 -tvf /db2/db2inst1/db_script.sql'
    become: true
    become_method: su
    become_user: db2inst1
    changed_when: true
```

and I have an error:

> "CONNECT TO DBNAME SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "DBNAME" could not be found.  SQLSTATE=42705"

but when i execute `/db2/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2 -tvf /db2/db2inst1/db_script.sql` directly on the server logged via db2inst1 it's executing corectly and there is no errors.

I searched IBM documentation and set default instance db2inst1 at db2set DB2INSTDEF and it is still not working. Does anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Assuming your Ansible task is not running locally on the Db2-server, then On the hostname that runs the ansible task, the remote database has to be catalogued in its db2-client, otherwise the db2 clp  will not know how to access the remote database. Lookup the commands in the Db2 Knowledge Centre ` catalog tcpip node ...`  (to catalog the remote Db2-server instance) followed by ` catalog database .. at .. `  ( to catalog the remote database on the node you just created).

Answer (score 0):

Check what is loaded from the *db2inst1* user's `.bashrc`. Does it *source* `$HOME/sqllib/db2profile` for example? So you have to do the same to run your db2 commands from Ansible. You might want to wrap this command in a shell-script and start that from Ansible which does a:

```
. $HOME/sqllib/db2profile
```

(And whatever more is needed) Before it starts the db2 command.

If you have more db2 commands you want to run in Ansible I would create a generic run script (e.g. `rundb2cmd.sh`) that loads the DB2 environment etc. and takes the arguments and execute them. In Ansible you could run it something like this:

```
- name: Execute db2 script
    ansible.builtin.shell: '/db2/db2inst1/db2runcmd.sh db2 -tvf /db2/db2inst1/db_script.sql'
    become: true
    become_method: su
    become_user: db2inst1
    changed_when: true
```

Comment: Thank you i got this, its executing but no result... its got schema init in script and after succesfully exec from ansible there is no schemas thre script work i tried it directly, but if i exec directly whole shell comand from ansible and it no result too

Comment: Hm so you're executing as the same user, in the same environment, but one after directly logging into the host it works and the other after 'become' through Ansible which doesn't work. There should be something in your environment that differs...

I would edit the playbook (or create a new one with the same code) in Ansible but as shell command use: `set > /home/db2inst1/env-ansible.txt`. Than I would log in as this user and type: `set > /home/db2inst1/env-shell.txt` and than run `diff /home/db2inst1/env-*.txt to see what is different.