# why do i still need to source the .bashrc or .profile even after using become user in ansible

Tags: shell, automation, ansible

- name : Test Play
  hosts : '{{hosts_list}}'
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name : Run command as db2 id
    ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd : db2level
    become: true
    become_user: db2icm1
    become_method : sudo

Comment: Because "change user id" doesn't mean "and also execute shell dotfiles".

Comment: @larsks are you saying then i need to source the .bashrc or .profile in order to  actually run a command as that user ... for example ... db2level  as the db2icm1 id

Comment: I'm not saying that: only you can answer the question of whether or not it is necessary. In general you don't need to source dotfiles in order to execute commands as a user, but if your dotfiles are setting up a custom environment, maybe you do! In which case, use a `shell` task and source them explicitly.

Comment: @larsks i see what you are saying .. thanks ! .... my  .bashrc file looks like this # The following three lines have been added by UDB DB2.
if [ -f /home/db2icm1/sqllib/db2profile ]; then
    . /home/db2icm1/sqllib/db2profile
fi
....  i would think when i came that user via ansible become_user ,  the become user logic would automatically call the  .bashc or .profile similar to a local login shell as if i were to sudo su - < user id >

Answer (score 0):

It is the same difference as running `su - db2icm1` vs. `su db2icm1` on your host. The first will switch to the user *db2icm1* and load it's profiles, but the second version only switches to this user.
Usually you set stuff for your *interactiv*e shell in your profile(s) so it makes sense that you don't want to execute this when running a command like through Ansible. So it doesn't support this.

But... in this case you need to load your `db2profile` because that is necessary for your DB2 command you want to run.

In another question I proposed to use a runscript which sources the DB2 profile `. /home/db2icm1/sqllib/db2profile` and then run's the (DB2) command you gave as arguments. And setup your Ansible playbooks using this. You can read the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76769695/11545324).